# Upload / Download BLOBs Jackrabbit

Tags: apache, upload, download, jackrabbit, sling

I'm looking for a way to provide upload/download mechanism for blob files.
These files should be stored in a jackrabbit datasource repository. I already discovered apache Sling framework for this task but it seems that this is not applicable for lare files (BLOBs) since it has it's own jackrabbit implementation and can not be used with my jackrabbit datasource repository. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://markmail.org/message/rcmsahf4n3olostm where your on-list question was answered.